# how to run python script/file multiple times

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am having python file/script (main1.py) in that file/script I did operations like count word, replace words and change string etc. I want to make .exe file of that script/file (main1.py), and want to run that file/script (main1.py) 50 times, and  In simple word if I run that .exe, my python file/script (main1.py) should run 50 times.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to make an executable? You can run a python script from the terminal with `python script.py`

Comment: What is changing everytime you run the script? Do you want it doing the exact same thing everytime? Also, why not making a loop in python?

Comment: If you don't need to make it an executable run the main.py in the terminal and put the code into a for loop which runs 40 times.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do some experiments. That why want to run script many time, without changing anything inside the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish or why.
But executing a python script from another python script multiple times can be achieved in two ways.

**1. Reimport**

When you import a script it is executed.

```
import importlib
import main1 # first execution

for _ in range(49): # other 49 executions
    importlib.reload(main1)
```

**2. Execute the script literally**

I would not recommend this approach but that way as you spawn a new python interpreter for each script execution.

```
import subprocess

python_executable = "python3" # depends on how your python interpreter executable is named
for _ in range(50):
    subprocess.run(["python3", "main1.py"])
```

---

To the implicit second part of your question, how to create an exe out of a python script, I don't know the answer to.